# Better ways to handle data corrections in Spark streaming

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

Spark structured streaming code needs to read the data from Kafka , perform deduplication check on a key and write to delta/target.

For dedup planning to use watermark as mentioned here - https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#streaming-deduplication.

**Question** - in case we need to handle data corrections from upstream or at our end in structured streaming code, what are the better ways to handle backfill? If data provider publish the corrected data to same Kafka queue and we use existing streaming job, we might miss the corrected data due to watermark already set.